# Testing a Video Conference Web Application

Tags: mobile, performance-testing

My team has created a video conference application that connects two users together through a web app. The users can share video and audio, as well as a text chat.

I am piecing together a test plan for this new web application and am looking for suggestions from the community on some key performance indicators and testing methods for mobile.

The majority of our users will access the app using an iPhone or Android. When testing on a desktop, I can use the browser's (likely chrome) dev tools built-in network throttling, but this is not available for mobile...

So, here is the question: **what are some good ways to performance test a one-on-one video chat web app on android and iPhone?**

Second question: **what are some good ways to performance test a one-on-one video chat web app in general**?

Comment: What do you have so far? What risks have you identified? Do you have a Product Coverage Outline or equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

As a software testing company we recommend to use '[Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/)' app to track network logs and performance on Android and iOS devices.

Comment: Seems the suggested application has a feature "Simulates slower internet connections" :)